# How to select column based on the MAX value when doing GROUP BY on different value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `MySQL` table `tbl` below:

[image]

now I run the following query:

```
SELECT DAY_NUMBER, WEEK_NUMBER, MAX(total_volume)
  FROM `tbl`
  GROUP BY WEEK_NUMBER
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Everything looks good except for the `DAY_NUMBER`. The `DAY_NUMBER` does not reflect the `TOTAL_VOLUME` from which I `query` the `MAX(TOTAL_VOLUME)`. If you look at `WEEK_NUMBER` `31`, the `MAX(TOTAL_VOLUME)` `777` has `DAY_NUMBER` `7` but the `query` has `5`.

My goal is to have `DAY_NUMBER` reflect `MAX(TOTAL_VOLUME)` value `DAY_NUMBER`.

could you please tell me how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tbl
  WHERE WEEK_NUMBER = t.WEEK_NUMBER AND total_volume > t.total_volume
)
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit more

Comment: This query returns the rows of the table for which `total_volume` is greater than any other total_volume of the same week_number. This is what NOT EXISTS does.

Comment: @forpas you need to alias tbl (and its columns) in the sub query otherwise you get everything not 1 entry per week as required.

Comment: @P.Salmon No it's not needed. The alias is needed only for the outer query. You can test it.

Comment: @P.Salmon Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oL6GNchwgqmomcjB9YnHPX/0

Comment: @forpas sorry missed the alias in the outer select

Answer (score 2):

Use like this,

```
SELECT DAY_NUMBER, WEEK_NUMBER, total_volume
  FROM `tbl` WHERE total_volume IN(SELECT MAX(total_volume)
  FROM `tbl`
  GROUP BY WEEK_NUMBER)
```

You will get Desired output

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oL6GNchwgqmomcjB9YnHPX/1 And I wonder who upvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `GROUP BY` for a query where you should be filtering.

I recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from tbl t
where t.total_volume = (select max(t2.total_volume)
                        from tbl t2
                        where t2.week_number = t.week_number
                       );
```

Alternatively, you can use window functions in MySQL 8+:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by week_number order by volume desc) as seqnum
      from tbl t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

With join

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(day_number int, week_number int, value int);

insert into t values
(1,1,10),(2,1,20),
(10,2,20),(11,2,10);

select t.day_number,t.week_number,t.value
from t
join
(select week_number,max(value) m
from t
group by week_number
) w on w.week_number = t.week_number and w.m = t.value;

+------------+-------------+-------+
| day_number | week_number | value |
+------------+-------------+-------+
|          2 |           1 |    20 |
|         10 |           2 |    20 |
+------------+-------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In the event of a draw you will get all days which match the max value.